# Remove category from url

Tags: functions, htaccess

I want to remove /category/ base from the permalinks. I tried the solution **http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category/**   but if i try pasting this in functions.php, i get the 404 error. I also tried `RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L]`   by pasting in **.htaccess**  , but still, i get 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make things easier why don't you use this plugin -> [WP No Category Base](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/)

Comment: As per your recommendations, i haven't modified the code and installed plugin. After installing plugin, if i make any change in wp-admin, all my posts give 404 error.

Answer (score -5):

To remove category base from url, go to wp-includes -> rewrite.php
line 1031 change

```
$this->category_structure = trailingslashit( $this->front . 'category' );
```

to

```
$this->category_structure = trailingslashit( $this->front  );
```

Comment: This is not the proper way to do it. You shouldn't be making changes to your core files.

Comment: DO NOT make what Shefali Aggarwal told you. You shouldn't change anything in the WordPress core. Any changes that you make there will vanish on the next upgrade, if first you don't break anything there. It's a really bad practice to do any changes on the core. Stay away from there.

Comment: Agreed.  There are plenty of filters for manipulating rewrites.