# How to display only the parent category in the permalink

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting

How it is possible to display only the parent category of the post. It contains two sub categories and I want to eliminate it.

Example:
myblog.com/parent_category/post_name

This is only what I want.

Comment: There's [a great post on how to do the opposite](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category) (remove parent, only show child category), which surely must contain the answer if you're capable but I don't have the WP/PHP-fu to edit this to a parent-only function. Any ideas? I'm also hoping to do this for my WP site.

Comment: These days, simply ensure child category AND parent category are selected for any given post and modern WordPress will use only the parent in URLs.

Answer (score 3):

You can try out this code here using `post_link` filter hook.

This filter is applied to the permalink URL for a post prior to returning the processed url by the function `get_permalink`. Now we are modifying that to suit our requirement i.e, to display only parent category for the child categories and then followed by the post name.

```
if ( ! is_admin() ){
 add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
}
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {
  // Get the categories for the post
  $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
  $parent_category = get_category($category[0]->parent);
  if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->parent == "271" ) {
    $permalink = trailingslashit( site_url('/'.$parent_category->slug.'/'.$post->post_name.'/' ) );
  }
  return $permalink;
}
```

Comment: Sure, the code here is using 'post_link' filter hook. This filter is applied to the permalink URL for a post prior to returning the processed url by the function get_permalink. Now we are modifying that to suit our requirement i.e, to display only parent category for the child categories and then followed by the post name.