# Create monthly archive for parent category

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting, archives

Part of the website I'm working on is meant to function like a monthly magazine, with a few different departments. So I have 'Magazine' set as the parent category, and say 'Art' and 'Music' as child categories (which may have further subcategories).

**THE GOAL**
I'm trying to set up a permalink structure so that, for example, `http://mysite.com/magazine/2014/12`
will show a page that contains all the posts from 'Magazine' and its subcategories for December, 2014.

**THE CURRENT STATE**
Currently, my permalink structure is set to: `/%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`

Going to the URL above effectively results in visiting `http://mysite.com/magazine/`—the posts are from multiple months.
However, visiting `http://mysite.com/art/2014/12` works, in that I see all 'Art' posts for the specified month.

Do I need a complex rewrite, or am going about this the wrong way? I came across this, which is basically the opposite of what I want to do: [Remove parent category from permalink? Basically only have the child category?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category).

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1**
I decided to temporarily remove my custom category template `category-magazine.php` and the magazine archive works correctly. So something with my template is breaking it. It's split into three loops (one for each department). Is that causing the problem perhaps???

**UPDATE 2**
So here is what I have in my multi-loop category-magazine archive:

```
    <?php // 1st Query
    $col1 = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'posts_per_page'            => 1,
            'cat'                       => 31
                )
            );
    ?>

    <?php if ( $col1->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="post-list group col-1">

            <?php while ( $col1->have_posts() ): $col1->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part('content'); ?>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

        </div><!--/.post-list-->


        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php /* The 2nd Query  */
        $col2 = new WP_Query(
            array(
                'posts_per_page'            => 1,
                'cat'                       => 28
            )
        );

        ?>

        <?php if ( $col2->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <div class="post-list group col-2">

            <?php while ( $col2->have_posts() ): $col2->the_post(); $col2->next_post(); ?>
            <?php echo get_template_part('content'); ?>
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


            </div><!--/.post-list-->

    <?php endif; ?> `
```

This works fine when visiting the magazine category page, but it doesn't work for archive pages.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I solved it:

I queried the year and month of the page we're on with:

```
$year     = get_query_var('year');
$monthnum = get_query_var('monthnum');
```

And then I added date parameters to each WP_Query:

```
        $col1 = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'year'                      => $year,
            'monthnum'                  => $monthnum,
            'posts_per_page'            => 1,
            'cat'                       => 31
            )
        );
```

This allows me to split the departments of the 'Magazine' archive page into different areas, rather than have them mixed in one loop.