# Does a parent page's post_title have to appear in a child page permalink?

Tags: permalinks, seo

If I have a page called `Home` and then a child page with Home as the parent, is there a way to avoid 'home' appearing in the permalink for the child page?

I've noticed this with a one-page scrolling theme which asks you to set lots of pages as child pages of the homepage. From an SEO perspective, its not great to have 'home' in all the permalinks.

[This question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category) seems relevant but refers to categories

Answer (score 0):

From the top of my head, yes.

URL has to uniquely identify target post (or set of posts) to load. One of the (often annoying) issues is that as result WordPress treats hierarchical and non–hierarchical post types differently.

In a nutshell hierarchical posts are identified by the *whole* path in URL, not just their individual slug. Likely you can tinker that away in principle, but such URL tweaks are considered unreliable and prone to cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/) ( when isn't there) you can use that allows you to modify the url in whatever way you'd like (https://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-manager/).

Also if it's hierarchical. It will redirect people from for example: /lp/test to /random/.

Hope that helps!

P.S. Im not in any way connected to the plugin owner, I just like it!