# Remove parent category from child/sub-category page URL in Wordpress

Tags: categories

I want to remove the parent category from sub-category page URL. (actually I need it only for a specific parent-category)

**f.e, convert the URL of all sub-categories pages under this parent-category, from:**

```
domain.com/parent-category/sub-category/
```

**to:**

```
domain.com/sub-category/
```

(BTW I have installed plugin that remove category base /category/ from posts and category URLs)

I would love to get help on this. Thanks.

Comment: Hope this helps [enter link description here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category)

Comment: Asiqur Rahman/. It is not working for me. I have found this free plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/. I simply go to the category settings page and change the URL there.