# What are the permalinks options for "Category" base and removing it?

Tags: theme-development, permalinks

Under "Settings > Permalinks", we can set up the default category base name to use for our category landing pages. For example, site.com/**categories**/my-first-category/.

Is there **a setting I can add to my functions.php** to allow the option to remove the category base and direct link to the category? For example, the above link becomes: site.com/my-first-category/

I realize that this opens up the possibility of having conflicting post names and category names (assuming I have a post slug that's the same as a category slug for example), but in this case, my post permalinks end in .html and my category permalinks will not, so there should never be a conflict (I expect).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best and Cleanest way to remove /category/ from category permalinks?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/best-and-cleanest-way-to-remove-category-from-category-permalinks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an answer to on how to do that in the WordPress way [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/best-and-cleanest-way-to-remove-category-from-category-permalinks)

but a faster way is using the .htaccess file by adding this line

```
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.yourblog.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

just make sure you change http://www.yourblog.com/ to what ever is needed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @בניית אתרים - Thanks! Its a shipping WP theme so I won't have direct access to htaccess for adding the filter. Can this be done from functions.php perhaps? How easy is it to undo?

Comment: @בניית אתרים: That does a redirect from the old style to the new style, but how does WordPress know that the new URLs are of this form? I think you need to add something to the WordPress rewrite rules too, otherwise it won't know what to do with incoming URLs of this form

Comment: @Scott B  - i think you are looking for somtheing like this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/best-and-cleanest-way-to-remove-category-from-category-permalinks

Comment: @Scott B - also look at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/ a plugin that does it for you.